# The $L^1(0, \infty)$ convergence of the sequence $f_n(x) = \frac{1-e^-x^2/n}{x^p}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

So, I've been asked the following:

> Let $$f_n(x) = \frac{1-e^{-\frac{x^2}{n}}}{x^p} \ \ x \in (0, \infty), n \in \mathbb{N}$$
>
> Depending on $p >0$, discuss the pointwise, uniform, and $L^1(0, \infty)$ convergence of the sequence $\{f_n\}$.

At the moment, I've been able to determine that the sequence converges pointwise for all $p > 0$ and that the sequences converges uniformly for $0 < p \leq 2$ (I took a look at the Taylor series of $f_n$). However, I'm not really sure what to say about the $L^1(0, \infty)$ convergence. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making the substitution $t=\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}$ the integral of $f_n$ becomes $$n^{\frac{1-p}{2}}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-t^2}}{t^p}dt=+\infty, \forall p >0$$

So the integrals of $f_n$ do  ot converge in $L^1 $ to $0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: make the substitution $t=\frac {x^{2}} n$. We get $\int_0^{\infty} f_n(x)dx=\frac 1 {n^{\frac {p+1} 2}} \int_0^{\infty} \frac {1-e^{-t}} {t^{\frac {p+1} 2}}dt$. Can you finish from here? [If $f_n$ converges in $L^{1}$ then it must converge to $0$ in $L^{1}$].